# Why is my react component not rendering with Link

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

[image: I imported my Category Page component to my app.js and used exact path]

The image is above ^^^
When I click on the link I see that the path is correct but when I try to redirect to that page it sends me back to the home page. I tried going to the route manually and it reroutes me to home. Why is my page not rendering?

Comment: From what I can see, I think your `UserProfile` component is being matched and rendered before `CategoryPage`. Inside the `Switch` component you should order your routes by `path` from more specific to less specific. `"/:userId"` is about as generic as `"/"`. Does `UserProfile` do any sort of redirect to the `"/"` route?

Comment: In userProfile use  /user/:userId then it should work else bring cateogory route infront at first row

Comment: @DrewReese yes the UserProfile would redirect the user to the user profile page.

Comment: No, I meant, is the `UserProfile` component being rendered and redirecting back to the home `"/"` path. Please also include all code and error messages as properly formatted and readable code snippets. Images are not searchable nor copy/pastable, and can be more difficult to read.

Comment: Thanks guys! I did what place a more specific path for the user profile and it worked! Thanks for tip guys!! And will do next time @DrewReese